# NSAppTransportSecurity for Exception of 2 domains

Tags: swift, info.plist, nsapptransportsecurity

Since my domain doesn't have an SSL Certificate atm I use the NSExceptionDomains to allow the domain to load anyway.

I use the following code in the Info.plist to allow both the domain and it's subdomains

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>infever.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

However, I'd like to pass through 2 domains this time since some parts of the app is from a different domain.

I tried just adding another key like this:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>infever.com</key>
        <key>gentsgroup.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

But that didn't work. What would be the proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<dict>
    <key>yourFirstDomain.com</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.2</string>
        <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.2</string>
        <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>yourSecondDomain.com</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.2</string>
        <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.2</string>
        <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

just copy this dictionary under your NSAppTransportSecurity and replace yourFirstDomain.com with you first domain and yourSecondDomain.com with your second domain

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This is for Per-Domain Exceptions only so seperating them might work. Otherwise you can completely disable ATS (look at the 2nd set of code)

Mutiple Domains (Seperate Dict's)

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>infever.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>gentsgroup.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Disable ATS Completely

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```